# Symfony2 validation messages translation. Fallback option does not works

Tags: php, validation, symfony, translation

I have SF2.3 at my webserver. I am using validatorBuilder to validate my data.

Here is my config:

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: ru } 
    default_locale:      ru
```

Here is my event listener:

```
// EventListener.php
...
$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
        ->enableAnnotationMapping()
        ->getValidator();
```

But when I get error messages they are in english, not in 'ru' locale. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have messages.ru.xliff in your bundle?

Comment: @AlbertoGaona no I don't. But I saw Validator has translation files for many languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$trans = new Translator('ru');
$trans->addLoader('xliff', new XliffFileLoader());
$trans->addResource('xliff',  __DIR__.'/../Resources/translations/validators.ru.xlf', 'ru', 'validators');

$this->validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
        ->enableAnnotationMapping()
        ->setTranslator($trans)
        ->setTranslationDomain('validators')
        ->getValidator();
```